# Get selected value from a dropdown L-5.1 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, drop-down-menu, http-post, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get the selected value using JavaScript and sending the value to the server side so as to process it using Laravel - PHP. This is code I've written so far, but I'm not getting it at the server side, is there anything I need to do more?

This is the blade file:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'created-products', 'method' => 'post'), array('id'=>'createproduct')) !!}
{!! Form::token() !!}

    @if(!Auth::check())
        <p><h3>Please login to create product</h3></p>
        @else
            <p>{!! Form::select('companyname', array('' => 'Select a Company') + $listCompanies, null, array('id'=>'companynameId')) !!} </p>
            <p>{!! Form::text('productname', Input::old('productname')) !!}</p>
            <p>{!! Form::hidden('hiddenCompanyName', '', array('id'=>'selectedCompanyHidden')) !!}</p>
            <p>{!! Form::submit('CREATE PRODUCT') !!}</p>
                    
    @endif

    <script>
        var returnedCompany = document.getElementById("companynameId");
        var storedCompany = returnedCompany.options[returnedCompany.selectedIndex].value;

        var hiddenCompanyId = document.getElementsByName('hiddenCompanyName');
        document.createproduct.hiddenCompanyId.value = storedCompany;
        document.forms["createproduct"].submit();
    </script>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the function to get the value from the blade file:

```
private static function compareCompany(ProductRequest $productRequest){
        $companyPicked = $productRequest->hiddenCompanyName;
        $listedCompanies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        $companies = new Company;
        if($companies->user_id === Auth::user()->id)
        {   
            foreach($listedCompanies as $company) {
                if($company->companyname === $companyPicked)
                {
                    return $company->id;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the function to save it into the DB.

```
public function store(ProductRequest $productRequest)
{
   $product = new Product;
    $company = new Company;
   if($productRequest->isMethod('post')){

   $product->user_id     = Auth::user()->id;
   $product->company_id  = $this->compareCompany($productRequest);
   $product->companyname = $productRequest->companyname;
   $product->productname = $productRequest->productname;

   $product->save();
   return redirect()->route('companyindex')->with('message', 'Your question has been posted.');
   }else{
        return redirect('company-create')->withErrors($productRequest)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` Returns a nodelist collection with a given name in the (X)HTML document. Try this: `var returnedCompany = document.getElementById("companynameId");
var storedCompany = returnedCompany.value;
document.getElementById('selectedCompanyHidden').value = storedCompany
document.forms["createproduct"].submit();`

Comment: Thanks, Rayon, I'll try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have now will submit the form before you doing any thing, you should add `onsubmit` event :

```
document.getElementById("createproduct").onsubmit=function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var returnedCompany = document.getElementById("companynameId");
    var storedCompany = returnedCompany.options[returnedCompany.selectedIndex].value;
    var hiddenCompanyId = document.getElementsByName('hiddenCompanyName')[0];

    document.createproduct.hiddenCompanyId.value = storedCompany;
    document.forms["createproduct"].submit();
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, @Zakaria, I've tried this but still giving a null response that it couldn't get the id. I believe, because I have tested it that the value selected is shown, but I'm not sure if the javascript is submitting any variable to the PHP / Laravel function to handle it.